# JPA - is it ok to default an id to 0?

Tags: java, jpa, hashcode

I have a simple entity with an auto-incrementing id.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long    id;
```

This has a hashCode method which was generated for me.

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
}
```

The problem is I'm trying to add auditing to this class but it calls hashCode before the entity is persisted and so id is null.

My solution (which works) is to initialize id to 0 until it can get it's proper value on persist.

```
private Long    id = 0L;
```

Question is whether this is acceptable or not? My fear is a changing hashCode is not good but then it has to be better than a NPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather fix your hashCode to deal with nulls. 
If you set id to 0, it will not be change upon persist.

Comment: You're right to make hashCode null safe. Actually I'm using jHipster and I've just found this bug which describes my exact problem. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/1177 
JPA was populating the id though even though I set it to 0. If it was a primitive long it would have to be 0. Maybe this behavior is not defined in the JPA spec but it was working.
As you say though fixing hashCode is a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: It may be implementation/(generation strategy)/(db autoincrement) specific. A while ago, if I set id myself the set value was used, but I have not tried it since the JPA update.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that JPA works with Java default values.

If your ID is a Wrapper, than a new entity must have the ID null.

If your ID is a int/long/etc than the default must be 0, 0L, etc.

If you set your ID Long = 0, JPA will understand that there is a Entity in the database with ID = 0 and probably say that your entity is detached.